# float the div when reducing the windows screen size

Tags: css, html

I am having problem of floating the div when reducing the windows screen size. What I would like to achieve is I have two div side by side, both div are floating left. When I reduce the browser windows screen size, and the right div will move to the bottom of the left div. Please see the screenshots below:
[image: Normal look when two divs fit in the browser window]

[image: After reduce the browser window size, and the right div will move at the bottom of left div]

At first, two divs are displayed side by side. After reduce the Browser windows size, the right div content will move to the bottom of the left div.

Comment: You're probably going to need to provide actual source code for us to evaluate. As far as I know what you're describing is the default behavior of floated elements and would have to be counteracted by something else.

Comment: what is with the width of the left and right div? Should they stay the same, when you reduce browser width, or should they adapt to the available space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a parent div, and fix the size of the children: http://jsfiddle.net/zV9ea/

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with a container.

## example

#### html

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="left"> Hello </div>
  <div class="right"> World </div>
</div>
```

#### css

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container .left {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  float: left;
}

#container .right {
  width: 760px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
```

See live: http://jsfiddle.net/s8wfx/

Comment: I tried your sample, but the blue div is still stay on the right size when I was reducing the Browser windows screen. The blue div does not move to the next of the pink div.

Comment: the HTML container itself will actually achieve this in my experience.  Unless the divs are conflicting with non-floated elements or are collapsing I don't know what would cause them to __not__ behave in this manner.