# Center two divs that are side-by-side, Float the div when reducing the windows screen size

Tags: html, css, formatting

I want to find out how to center two content until a certain threshold when the window is minimized width-wise it will put the content on the right below.

In this page, the image on the left with description on the right. When page is minimized to a certain width size, it put the name and description below.

http://artloft.co/products/wacho-rice-mill

So there are three parts to this question:
1) How to minimize the div dynamically (I'm thinking some width %)
2) How are they centered when the width is expanded/maximized
3) How to put one div on top of the other when width is decreased/minimized.

I found a part of the answer here, but without the other two, I don't understand how they can be incorporated.
[float the div when reducing the windows screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914894/float-the-div-when-reducing-the-windows-screen-size/9915061#9915061)

Much appreciated

Comment: google for media queries

Answer (score 0):

This is done using media queries to recognize the screen resolution.

**[More info on media queries here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)**

[I've made a simple demo for you to inspect the code](http://jsfiddle.net/7pa2op35/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

This has a wrapper `center` which centers the two divs after a certain resolution. And a div `clear` that clears the space after two floating elements.

**CSS**

```
.left{width:100%; height:100px; background:green;}
.right{width:100%; height:100px; background:blue; float:left;}
.clear{clear:both;}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .left{width:50%; height:100px; background:green; float:left;}
  .right{width:50%; height:100px; background:blue; float:left;}
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .center{margin:0 auto; width:800px;}
}
```

The top CSS is for the smallest screen resolutions. The media queries after that, check for screen resolutions, when these are recognized, the CSS becomes active.

So, for your smallest screen resolution (in my example everything below 600px), your CSS is:

```
.left{width:100%; height:100px; background:green;}
.right{width:100%; height:100px; background:blue; float:left;}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

Then the first media query checks if the screen resolution is larger than 600px, if this is the case, the following classes are ADDED

```
  .left{width:50%; height:100px; background:green; float:left;}
  .right{width:50%; height:100px; background:blue; float:left;}
```

The next media query checks if the screen is larger than 900px, if this is the case, the following classes are ADDED

```
.center{margin:0 auto; width:800px;}
```

[**See the working code in a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7pa2op35/)

Resize the lower right screen to see the different queries in action.

Answer (score 0):

Resize the window to see the difference or press ctrl+shift+m in firefox

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/myodeevy)

```
* ,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;    
}
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
#container{
padding:10px;
  text-align:left;
}
.content{
    text-align:justify;
}
.left_image{
  float:left;
  margin:0 20px 10px 0;
  }
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
  #container{
padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
  .left_image{
    float:none;
    margin:10px auto;
  }
  .content{
    text-align:justify;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tough about using Jquery?
You can change css attries with jQuery, as an example (this is just tough, not code you can use, i dont remeber statements so clearly out of my mind)

```
if($( window ).width() < 500px) {
$('#div1').css(do what ever you want to the css)
}
```